# When writing a file, permissions are write only

Tags: files, permissions, c

I opened a file in C and wrote it with this code:

```
int fd = open("soandso.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
write(fd, buf_of_data, 3);
```

The file now has write permission only for me and that is not what I specified in open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste the output of `ls -l soandso.txt` . Also, if there is some more code than you've shown, please paste it using some pastebin service.

Comment: This is the only file manipulation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File creation permissions are modified by the `umask` value.

So, for example:

```
$ umask
0022
$ touch xyz
$ ls -l xyz
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Sep 22 08:37 xyz
```

The umask value matches the standard *rwx* pattern, and so a value of `0022` *removes* `----w--w-` permissions from the newly created file.

We can change this:

```
$ umask 002
$ touch abc
$ ls -l abc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Sep 22 08:38 abc
```

Now the 002 mask only removes `-------w-`

To create files with no masking

```
$ umask 0
$ touch def
$ ls -l def
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sweh sweh 0 Sep 22 08:40 def
```

If you want your program to ignore the `umask` value then you must explicitly call the `umask(2)` function before calling `open(2)`

Note that when using `open(2)` with the `O_CREAT` flag then you should also pass a permission *mode*.
eg

```
open("myfile",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0666);
```

In this case the mode field is also modified via the `umask` value so the actual mode of the creation is `(mode & ~umask)`.

Comment: "then you must explicitly call the umask(2) function" ... or pass the mode as argument 3 to the `open()` call.

Comment: @Patrick `umask` modifies the mode value as well in this case.

Comment: Hence why I said "or". Though I would argue that passing the mode is the proper method. Especially considering if you want to set bits, such as those >= 01000, or the executable bits. Neither of which the umask method will handle.

Comment: @Patrick if you do `open("foo",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0666)` and have a umask of 022 then the resulting file will still be 0644.  If you want want to create a 666 file then you must clear the umask first.   If you don't need to _create_ it 0666 then you can `chmod()` the file after creation.

Comment: So should I be passing a third argument to `open()`?

Comment: @MarkYisri You need to do both; the manpage for `open(2)` says that you must specify a `mode` value when using `O_CREAT`.  And you need to ensure the `umask` matches what you want to ensure the result is what you want.

Comment: @StephenHarris Okay, I'll try passing the third argument. I've never changed my `umask` so that shouldn't be a problem (other applications work fine).

Comment: @StephenHarris That worked. Please edit your answer to show this info and I'll mark it as accepted.